# Showing a Windows form on a secondary monitor?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors, setbounds

I'm trying to set a Windows Form on secondary monitor, as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MatrixView n = new MatrixView();
    Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
    setFormLocation(n, screens[1]);
    n.Show();
}

private void setFormLocation(Form form, Screen screen)
{
    // first method
    Rectangle bounds = screen.Bounds;
    form.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);

    // second method
    //Point location = screen.Bounds.Location;
    //Size size = screen.Bounds.Size;

    //form.Left = location.X;
    //form.Top = location.Y;
    //form.Width = size.Width;
    //form.Height = size.Height;
}
```

The properties of bounds seem correct, but in both methods I've tried, this maximizes the form on the primary monitor.  Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure, the WindowState on MatrixView isn't *Maximized*, is it?

Comment: @Austin No, the WindowState is Normal.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Try setting StartPosition parameter as `FormStartPosition.Manual` inside your `SetFormLocation` method.

Comment: Yeah, doing form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; did the trick.  Any idea why?

Comment: @Henk No, it's Windows Forms.  Here's a link to it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition(VS.80).aspx

Comment: From MSDN: 

"Setting  WindowStartupLocation to  Manual causes a window to be positioned according to its  Left and  Top property values. If either the  Left or  Top properties aren't specified, their values are determined by Windows."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx

Comment: where is WindowStartUpLocation? I can't find it

Comment: If your form is maximized you have firstly to set `this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;` and then move form to other screen

Comment: is it possible to force resolution to 4: 3?

Answer (score 62):

```
this.Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
```

this is the Form reference.

Comment: However it seems that it is ordered by some other criteria than Window's monitor configuration. My primary for example was at position [1] while my second monitor was at [0].

Comment: will not work if you set location where from you creating form instance. like works on form load

Answer (score 12):

@Gengi's answer is succinct and works well. If the window is maximised it does not move the window. This snippet solves that (although I suspect the windows "normal" dimensions must be smaller than the new screen dimensions for this to work):

```
    void showOnScreen(int screenNumber)
    {
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

        if (screenNumber >= 0 && screenNumber < screens.Length)
        {
            bool maximised = false;
            if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                maximised = true;
            }
            Location = screens[screenNumber].WorkingArea.Location;
            if (maximised)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure `screens[1]` is your secondary?  Give `screens[0]` a try. Your code is basically correct.

---

Ok, I checked, you will have to do it after the Show():

```
n.Show();
setFormLocation(n, screens[1]);
```

which gives some unwanted flicker. But you can probably do:

```
n.SetBounds(-100, -100, 10, 10);  // or similar
n.Show();
setFormLocation(n, screens[1]);
```

Comment: Relatively sure - using screens[0] and screens[1] give the same result.

Answer (score 3):

To display form on secondary screen:

```
    Screen primaryFormScreen = Screen.FromControl(primaryForm);
    //Use this if you are looking for secondary screen that is not primary
    Screen secondaryFormScreen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Primary) ?? primaryFormScreen;
    //Use this if you are looking for screen that is not being used by specific form
    Screen secondaryFormScreen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Equals(primaryFormScreen)) ?? primaryFormScreen;
    //Putting the form on the other screen
    secondaryForm.Left = secondaryFormScreen.Bounds.Width;
    secondaryForm.Top = secondaryFormScreen.Bounds.Height;
    //Recommended to use, You can change it back later to the settings you wish
    secondaryForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    secondaryForm.Location = secondaryFormScreen.Bounds.Location;
    Point p = new Point(secondaryFormScreen.Bounds.Location.X, secondaryFormScreen.Bounds.Location.Y);
    secondaryForm.Location = p;
    secondaryForm.Show();
```

If you are looking forward for a specific screen, you can loop on "Screen.AllScreens" and use the process above.

Comment: What is `secondaryForm` and where is it declared in your or OP's code?

Comment: `secondaryForm` is a `Form` type of object where i set it's location to be within the `secondaryFormScreen` bounds. It doesn't have to be `Form` depending on what you are using, you can set similar bounds the same way i did to the form to allocate within the other screen

Answer (score 1):

I used this for an XNA 4 Dual Screen Application (Full Screen XNA Game Window + WinForm)

In the Form_Load() method, place the following code:

```
var primaryDisplay = Screen.AllScreens.ElementAtOrDefault(0);  
var extendedDisplay = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => s != primaryDisplay) ?? primaryDisplay;

this.Left = extendedDisplay.WorkingArea.Left + (extendedDisplay.Bounds.Size.Width / 2) - (this.Size.Width / 2);
this.Top = extendedDisplay.WorkingArea.Top + (extendedDisplay.Bounds.Size.Height / 2) - (this.Size.Height / 2);
```

Comment: I know I'm late on this, but for anyone else looking at this. Primary display is NOT always element 0 in the list, so this doesn't reliably get the primary display. However this did lead me to the solution using the Primary property of Screen. var primaryMonitor = Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => s.Primary).FirstOrDefault();
var secondaryScreens = Screen.AllScreens.Where(s => !s.Primary).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Set form Startup Position property to Manual

```
    public void MoveWindowToProjector ()  
    { 
           Rectangle rectMonitor;

            // Create New Process
            Process objProcess = new Process();

            //Get All the screens associated with this Monitor
            Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;

            // Get Monitor Count
            int iMonitorCount = Screen.AllScreens.Length;

            // Get Parameters of Current Project
            string[] parametros = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
           // if (parametros.Length > 0)
           // {
                //objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = parametros[0];
               // objProcess.Start();
          //  }
            // Get Window Handle of this Form
            IntPtr hWnd = this.Handle;

            Thread.Sleep(1000);


            if (IsProjectorMode)
            {
                if (iMonitorCount > 1) // If monitor Count 2 or more
                {
                    //Get the Dimension of the monitor
                    rectMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Get the Dimension of the monitor
                    rectMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                rectMonitor = Screen.AllScreens[0].WorkingArea;

            }
            if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                SetWindowPos(hWnd, 0,
                    rectMonitor.Left, rectMonitor.Top, rectMonitor.Width,
                    rectMonitor.Height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method shows forms on selected screen from left to right:

```
void ShowFormsOnScreenLeftToRight(Screen screen, params Form[] forms)
    {
        if (forms == null || forms.Length == 0)
            return;

        var formsCnt = forms.Length;
        var formSize = new Size(screen.WorkingArea.Size.Width / formsCnt, screen.WorkingArea.Size.Height);
        for (var i = 0; i < formsCnt; i++)
        {
            var form = forms[i];
            if (form == null)
                continue;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            form.Location = new Point(screen.WorkingArea.Left + screen.WorkingArea.Size.Width / formsCnt * i, 0);
            form.Size = formSize;
            form.BringToFront();
        }
    }
```

To solve your problem, you should run:

```
ShowFormsOnScreenLeftToRight(n, Screen.AllScreens.First(s => !s.Primary));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
                sc aoc = new sc();
                aoc.Show();
    aoc.Location = Screen.AllScreens[INDEX OF YOUR AVAILABLE SCREENS TARGET].WorkingArea.Location;
```

> FOR MAXIMIZED WINDOW STATE

```
aoc.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

> FOR ANY X,Y POSITION

```
aoc.Location = new Point(TARGET X POSITION, TARGET Y POSITION);
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, it just puts it on my primary monitor nomatter what