# How do I ensure a form displays on the "additional" monitor in a dual monitor scenario?

Tags: c#, winforms, multiple-monitors

I have an application in which there is a form which I want to show on second screen.

Mean If application is running on screen A and when I click on menu to show Form it should display on Screen B
 and same with if application is running on screen B and when I click on menu to show Form it should display on Screen A.

Comment: What if there are three monitors?

Comment: the app will run on dual screen only.

Comment: Are you **sure**? What happens when one of your users buys a third monitor? What happens if the app is used over Remote Desktop?

Comment: we will provide the system with dual screen only to user:)

Comment: This question (and the accepted answer) are more specific and therefore not an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor . Both questions are complementary.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use the [`Screen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx) class to find a screen that the original form is not on, then set the second form's `Location` property based on that screen's `Bounds`.

For example:

```
var myScreen = Screen.FromControl(originalForm);
var otherScreen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Equals(myScreen)) 
               ?? myScreen;
otherForm.Left = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Left + 120;
otherForm.Top = otherScreen.WorkingArea.Top + 120;
```

This will work for any number of screens.

Note that it is possible that the video card is configured so that Windows sees one large screen instead of two smaller ones, in which case this becomes much more difficult.

Comment: if the originator form is not available??

Comment: I have two screens set as "extended" on my Windows7. If I use your code my window remain on first screen because otherScreen.WorkingArea is always placed on (0,0); I had to use otherScreen.Bounds to move windows on top-left of second screen. Am I correct?

Comment: More: _(s => s != myScreen)_ is not working; I had to use _(s => !s.Equals(myScreen))_

Comment: Good answer! In a short code it provides exactly what is asked for, and even a safe fallback to using the same screen if only one is available, plus a hint on how to position the Form relative to that screen. Notice that `WorkingArea` is the area where the form would be viewable (not hidden by e.g. the task bar), and it is equal to `Bounds` when there are no bars or borders (like the task bar). Notice that the task bar may actually be on the secondary screen.

Comment: I had to set `otherForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual` for this to work.

Comment: You should use the `Bounds` property, as stated by @Marco

Answer (score 21):

Below is a function allowing you to display a form on any monitor.  For your current scenario you can call this `showOnMonitor(1);`.

Essentially you have to get screen information from `Screen.AllScreens` and then get the dimensions of each, then place your form where you need it

```
function void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor) 
{ 
    Screen[] sc; 
    sc = Screen.AllScreens; 

    Form2 f = new Form2(); 

    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
    f.Left = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left; 
    f.Top = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top; 
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 

    f.Show(); 
}
```

Note don't forget to do validation to ensure you actually have two screens etc else an exception will be thrown for accessing `sc[showOnMonitor]`

Comment: This still does not completely answer the question.

Comment: It should be 
  f.Left = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left; 
  f.Top = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top;

Answer (score 12):

On the OnLoad method change the Location of the window.

```
protected void Form1_OnLoad(...) {
    showOnMonitor(1);
}

private void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor) 
{ 
    Screen[] sc; 
    sc = Screen.AllScreens; 
    if (showOnMonitor >= sc.Length) {
        showOnMonitor = 0;
    }

    this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
    this.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left, sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);
    // If you intend the form to be maximized, change it to normal then maximized.
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Why not just `this.Location = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Location`?

Comment: Yes you can do that too.

Comment: @Nap, Does your code work if i connect the second monitor via hdmi port?

Comment: @M_Mogharrabi I was able to test with vga and hdmi ports.

Answer (score 2):

I used this for an XNA 4 Dual Screen Application (Full Screen XNA Game Window + WinForm)

In the Form_Load() method, place the following code:

```
var primaryDisplay = Screen.AllScreens.ElementAtOrDefault(0);  
var extendedDisplay = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => s != primaryDisplay) ?? primaryDisplay;

this.Left = extendedDisplay.WorkingArea.Left + (extendedDisplay.Bounds.Size.Width / 2) - (this.Size.Width / 2);
this.Top = extendedDisplay.WorkingArea.Top + (extendedDisplay.Bounds.Size.Height / 2) - (this.Size.Height / 2);
```