# Specifying startup window/form location on multiple displays

Tags: c#

I have two displays (two monitors) connected to my machine, and I noticed a strange thing happening today. I had an Explorer window open with my compiled exe on my primary display, and when I double-clicked it, it opened in the primary display (left monitor). However if I pressed enter to launch the executable, it started in the secondary display (right monitor). The window state of the initial form is maximized. Is there a way to tell C# to open the initial form in the primary display?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Does anybody know what causes pressing enter vs double-clicking to result in diff behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    f.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Location;

    Application.Run(f);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this: [Show form on primary or secondary screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/c-winform-show-form-in-second-screen-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

```
Screen[] myScreen = Screen.AllScreens;
this.Location = myScreen[0].WorkingArea.Location; // Primary Screen
this.Location = myScreen[1].WorkingArea.Location; // Secondary Screen
```

Comment: Please add some explanations with your code as well.