# Controlling output to a TV display while control panel is on laptop screen?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, multiple-monitors

I have a program written in VB.Net with Visual Studio 2008.  I have one window form to display on a laptop that controls the information seen/sent on another form that is to be continually displayed on an output from the laptop to a TV, Projector or Monitor.

Or I would like to accomplish this:

Computer/laptop - Has window form 1 that controls the program
TV/Ouput - Has window form 2 that shows updated data on the screen for people to see

I do not want people to see the control form that is on the laptop.

**Is their a way to assign a form to use an output to other screen only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create two forms, one is the control panel with startup on the primary screen (default). For the other form, set the location to that of the secondary screen (i.e. TV or projector). To do this, iterate through i.e. Screen.AllScreens.Where(x=>!x.Primary).First(). The WorkingArea property gives the rectangle in which to place the second form.

Answer (score 1):

Try this application. I had developed it for our local channel...

http://www.mediafire.com/file/dq01lf4zbasstso/Videobox%20%28dual%20screen%20video%20player%29.zip

or try this...

http://www.mediafire.com/file/mahr69wdll5l5yn/now%20showing.zip

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to send text to the second form?

Will following work or am I not understanding your question?

```
frm2.label1.text = me.textbox1.text
```

Regards

Jake

Comment: I want to output one form to a tv output and have another form on the monitor.  I have the communications between forms working ok.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand your problem...

There are several ways of making 2 forms to communicate, one could have a reference to the other, or you could have some "manager" or "controller" class that knows about both of them. If both forms are from different apps you must resort to sockets, named pipes, a message queue, have some middle layer like a webservice, etc.

About sending the display... again, I don't know if I've understood you, if both the form1 and form2 are located in the same computer, you can use System.Windows.Forms.Screen to get the laptop monitor and TV information, like their resolution and coordinates, and locate the forms themselves or other content in the corresponding screen.

Comment: The forms communicate ok.  I want to assign form1 to display on laptop only and form2 to display on the tv output only.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to go ahead.

A. Using separate Projector or monitor as second monitor for your laptop(Dual Monitor).

To start with the configuration of dual monitor refer [this](http://www.microsoft.com/athome/organization/twomonitors.aspx) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307873).

For this kind of setup your both forms would be running on the same machine. To adjust the display form on second monitor refer [this](http://predicatet.blogspot.com/2007/01/show-c-windows-forms-on-dual-monitor.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/c-winform-show-form-in-second-screen-and-vice-versa)
Controlling the second form can be achieved by creating instance of that form and controlling the instance from first form.

B. Using two machines one as controller and second as presenter.

For this kind of setup. You will need two applications to run. And need socket(TCP/UDP) communication to communicate between both.

I feel you are looking for first solution.