# C/C++/C# Set Window Position on a monitor

Tags: c#, c++, c, window, monitor

I want to move a Window (HWND) in a second monitor. The thing is that I tried many things like double the resolution or putting negative values and it never was able to put the window on my second monitor.

Any clue of how to do that in C/C++/c#

Comment: Please pick one language and one framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Screen and the Form.StartPosition should get you there.

See the first answer to this post (for C#/WinForms solution): [How do I ensure a form displays on the "additional" monitor in a dual monitor scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/c-winform-show-form-in-second-screen-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

The desktop layout is user-configurable, a second monitor can be to the left, to the right, above, below, or positioned weirdly compared to the primary.

The [`GetMonitorInfo`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetMonitorInfo.html) function will help you find out where the second monitor is, in virtual screen coordinates.  [As @holtavolt mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704655/c-c-c-sert-window-position-on-a-monitor/7704700#7704700), the .NET `Screen` class is a convenient wrapper.