# How to place an instance of my windows form on each monitor of a extended desktop

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C# winform Show form in second screen and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561104/c-sharp-winform-show-form-in-second-screen-and-vice-versa)

I got a extended desktop with 2 or 3 monitors.
I'm trying to have my C# windows form application place a instance of itself on each of these monitors.
Is this even possible? if so how?

Comment: I agree, @DennisTraub, it can be solved using the knowledge from the link