# How to open form2 on the second monitor?

Tags: c#

I create Form2 from Form1. I want that Form2 opens on the second monitor. How I can do this?
I use this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 dlg = new Form2();
    dlg.Show();
}
```

How to change this code for this?
Thanks for all.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor

Answer (score 8):

Use this code

```
Form2 dlg = new Form2();
Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
Rectangle bounds = screen[1].Bounds;
dlg.SetBounds(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
dlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
dlg.Show();
```

Comment: I am not sure that only this will solve the her problem. She needs somehow to set the `Position` of the form.

Comment: And how is it possible to set position of the form?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this

```
Screen[] sc; 
sc = Screen.AllScreens; 
//get all the screen width and heights 
Form2 f = new Form2(); 
f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
f.Left = sc[neededmonitor].Bounds.Width; 
f.Top = sc[neededmonitor].Bounds.Height; 
f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
f.Show();
```

Comment: But can I check this if (exist.sc[1]) { show form on the second monitor} else { on 1 monitor }. sc[1] = what's type of data?

Comment: Data type is Screen. You can check length of sc. Length = number of allowed screens. if(sc.Length>1) { show form on the second monitor}

Answer (score 0):

And you can detect secondary monitor (using System.Linq) like this:

```
var screen = Screen.AllScreens.FirstOrDefault(s => !s.Primary && s.DeviceName.Contains("DISPLAY2"));
```