# Win form opening position change on show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to open winform on secondary screen with code below

```
ff.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
ff.Left = sc[1].Bounds.Left; value 1366
ff.Top = sc[1].Bounds.Top;
ff.Height = sc[1].Bounds.Height;
ff.Width = sc[1].Bounds.Width;

Console.WriteLine(ff.Left); // output 1366

ff.Show();

Console.WriteLine(ff.Left); // output 50
```

Why value got changed on show and because of that form open in  primary screen. Even in Visual studio property window when i try to change x,y parameter of location, values updated to old values once i leave property cell. What can be the issue.

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor

Comment: If you care about the position of the window on the screen then you *must* use the Load event.  When it fires, the small changes to the window size due to user preferences are applied.  And the changes due to the video DPI setting, forcing the form to rescale.  Big changes.  Only then can you align the window correctly.  The StartPosition property is irrelevant.  One of the few good reasons to use the Load event btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `StartPosition` property of the form `ff` to `Manual`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `StartUpLocation` parameter as "manual" for the `ff` form.

Comment: i am not able to find windowstartuplocation property in winform.