# Attempting to show screensaver on all screens, only shows on one screen

Tags: c#, winforms, screensaver

I'm attempting to make a screensaver with a Windows Form App. It's almost working correctly, but for whatever reason, it will not show on all of the screens, just one of them.

```
foreach (Screen screen in Screen.AllScreens)
{
    Screensave screensaver = new Screensave(screen.Bounds);
    screensaver.Show();
}
```

Now this creates the correct amount of instances of the program. But all of them are on only one of my screens, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: This post describes a few useful moments: [Showing a Windows form on a secondary monitor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363374/showing-a-windows-form-on-a-secondary-monitor). It is necessary to set `form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual`

Comment: Read the notes here about the VirtualScreen: [Using SetWindowPos with multiple monitors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026765/7444103), to also select, in different ways, where a window should be presented. Don't skip the DpiAwaress part.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess without knowing the `Screensave` code. My guess is the the `Show` function, is opening a `Dialog`

As you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1), the function returns a result

```
public System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult ShowDialog();
```

If that's the case your loop will pause `screensaver.Show();` until you close the dialog.

Comment: No, this isn't showing a dialogue. All of the instances _are_ visible, they just are stacked on top of each other on the first monitor.

Comment: Can you share the `Screensave` class? I can't guess what's happening under the hood

Comment: It's not the cleanest code, but [here](https://pastebin.com/BNqMxgjj)